# How to convert swift program to objective c

Tags: ios

I am trying to convert this code to o objective c but I am facing problem I am new in objective c I  do not have an idea about objective c

```
do {
                    let myJSON =  try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                    if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                        var msg : String!

                        msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                        print(msg)

                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }

            }

            task.resume()
```

please help me this

Answer (score 0):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray * myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
if error!= nil
{
  NSLog(@"%@",error);
}
if myJSON!=nil
{
  NSString * msg = [myJSON objectForKey:@"message"];
  NSLog(@"%@",msg);
}
```

This code will work for JSON serialization.

Comment: how do you add try and catch  ,NSDictionary in swift code

Comment: you don't need to add try catch block in objective C as the error is catched inside NSError.

Comment: myJSON  is your NSDictionary.Do you want code in swift or objective C?